# How to fetch and display data at the same time from MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to display data from a table from a MYSQL database using PHP OOP. However, I'm not sure if I'm unable to display the data because I'm not actually fetching the data in the first place.

I've tried fetching and displaying the data using only a PHP array and no HTML in my method and I figured this wouldn't be working because I wasn't using HTML list tags to format the data from the database. I've considered using a HTML table but I have seen displays from databases using lists work a few times before and I want to know why this doesn't work how it should.

I've tested for MYSQL connection and it does exist.

*** M_PRODUCTS.PHP ***

```
<?php  

class Products 
{
    private $Conn;
    private $db_table = "toys"; 

    function __construct() {
        // here we're making sure that the connection from $conn in "init.php" is transferred 
        // into our own private $conn property for usage in this object
        global $Conn; 
        $this->Conn = $Conn;
    }

        // fetches and displays all products from db
        public function fetch_all_products($id = NULL)
        { 
            if ($id == NULL)
            {
                $data = []; 
                if ($result = $this->Conn->query("SELECT * FROM " . $this->db_table . " ORDER BY name"))
                {
                    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
                    {
                        while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
                        {
                            $data = array(
                            "id" => $row["product_id"],
                            "name" => $row["name"],
                            "price" => $row["price"],
                            "image" => $row["image"]
                            ); 
                        } 
                        return $data; 
                    }
                else 
                {
                    return "<h1>Oops... Something went wrong!</h1>"; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*** INDEX.PHP ***

```
<?php include("init.php"); 
      include("models/m_products.php"); 
?>

<body>
    <div id="whitespace">

        <?php

$products = fetch_all_products();

?>
      <?php foreach($products as $row) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->price; ?></td>
        <td><img src="<?php echo $row->image_path(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $row->name; ?>" width="100" /></td>

      </tr>
      <?php } ?>

    </div>
</body>
```

I expect the images of my products to be displaying in my index.html file. However, nothing appears.

I also get this error message in the JavaScript console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). This would explain a lot but as I said I tested my database connection and it works. I'm not sure how or why this message is coming from the JavaScript console if I'm not using JavaScript. I thought it would be worth mentioning anyway.

Comment: Looks like you are missing `echo`, that is all. For example `echo $Products->fetch_all_products();` or even `<?=$Products->fetch_all_products()?>` - This is assuming you have everything else correct.

Comment: Did you echo the received data like ```echo $Products->fetch_all_products()```, Thanks

Comment: I've just made the change now. The images still haven't appeared.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code the function returns some data, but the thing is that you have not printed it, so instead of `return` in the function you can use `echo` or just put

```
echo $Products->fetch_all_products();
```

Comment: I've just made the change now. The images still haven't appeared.

Comment: @Harrison according to your code you are making `echo` if something went wrong otherwise making `return`, so it means that if everything is ok still there will not be any output seen

Comment: where exactly am I doing that? I've changed "return $data" to "echo $data" in the "fetch_all_products" method. Is that what you mean? The products still don't appear when I do that.

Comment: @Harrison the thing is that in `M_PRODUCTS.PHP` I don't see your changes

Comment: I've replaced "return $data" with "echo $data" in the method. I've also echoed the method in index.php.

Comment: @Harrison it seems you are mixing everything, in your case you can either keep `returns` in the function and make `echo` function result or you must just call the function and put `echos` in the function

Comment: @Harrison also in your `M_PRODUCTS.PHP` you are concatenating string with the array: `$data .= array(`, I don`t even know what it can give.

Comment: OK, yes this makes sense. I now have "return $data" in the method instead of "echo $data". I have also got rid of the "<li>" tags and the concatenation in the method. Now it is just an associative array, after trying again... Still no result. I'm wondering if I should present my code connecting to the database.

Comment: @Harrison first of all if everything ok, then you have `echo array()` which is not good, and the second your function will not return anything in case `($result->num_rows > 0)` is `false`

Answer (score 0):

Strange code, I would do something like that. 
**1. First the function** find all()
**2. index.php** echo - output

```
<?php

$products = find_all_products();

?>
      <?php foreach($products as $row) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->price; ?></td>
        <td><img src="<?php echo $row->image_path(); ?>" width="200" /></td>

      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct your comparison operator it should be.
 `if ($id == NULL)` 
instead of

```
if ($id = NULL)
```

in your function `fetch_all_products()`.

correct the code in index.php to print an array use `print_r()` or loop through the result array.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Corrected the first part. Understood. The function "print_r" prints only the final product of the array and in an associative array format which I don't want. I want the values printed out only, not the keys. That includes the product image.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 major issues I can see in your code 
1) you need to update your comparison operator from

```
if ($id = NULL)
```

to

```
if ($id == NULL)
```

2) you need to update your code in index.php from

```
<body>
    <div id="whitespace">
        <h1><?php echo shop_name ?></h1>

        <?php

        echo $Products->fetch_all_products();

        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

to

```
<body>
    <div id="whitespace">

        <?php

$products = find_all_products();

?>
      <?php foreach($products as $row) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->price; ?></td>
        <td><img src="<?php echo $row->image_path(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $row->name; ?>" width="100" /></td>

      </tr>
      <?php } ?>


    </div>
</body>
```

I hope it will sort out your issue

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Your code generally makes sense but there are some issues with it in my project. Firstly, in index.php, I had to change "find_all_products()" to "fetch_all_products" as that is the method used in m_products.php. Though, even after doing this I was still getting an "undefined function" error message. So I used "$products = $Products->fetch_all_products" and that got rid of the error. Now I am stuck with this error: "Notice: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in..." and "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in..."

Comment: You need to do following steps:
1) Make sure M_PRODUCTS.PHP is a class and included in INDEX.PHP
2) Create Object of M_PRODUCTS.PHP class and then try to get the results.

Comment: And you can use whatever the function name, I am just trying to give you idea about the logic behind it.

Comment: Above I've included all the none CSS code for m_products.php and index.php. Number 1 has been done. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by number 2. I've created an object within the class. The error code I am now getting is: Fatal error: Cannot declare class Products, because the name is already in use in C:\MAMP\htdocs\web_apps\shopping_cart\models\m_products.php on line 3.